How can explain with text difference time in Python?
I have dataframe and it has a time diffrence column. The column has like bellow values. I would like to create a new column and write in it like someting that: 1 hour, 11 minutes, 45 seconds.
How to do that simple way on Python?
20   0 days 01:11:45
21   0 days 01:11:45
22   0 days 01:11:45
23   0 days 01:11:45
24   0 days 01:11:45
25   0 days 01:11:45
26   0 days 01:11:45
27   0 days 01:11:45
28   0 days 01:11:45
29   0 days 01:11:45

I am new at pyhton so I do have any idea what I can try.

What's the relationship between the numbers that you say you want, and the numbers/data in your example?
Can you give the example column names, so we know what those numbers etc mean?
Do you just want to reformat the time-difference column so that it includes the text that describes each different time-unit as a "long-text" format?

as far i understand your query
i assume your last column name is 'time'
then for new column('time_components') you can create like follow
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

# Extract hours, minutes, and seconds into a new column
df['time_components'] = df['time'].dt.components['hours'].astype(str) + ' hours, ' + df['time'].dt.components['minutes'].astype(str) + ' minutes, ' + df['time'].dt.components['seconds'].astype(str) + ' seconds' 

